# Should I be worried about a 1-year-old getting excited and grabbing and scratching people's faces hard?

Tags: toddler, language-development, violence, grandparents

I'm grandmother of a 1-year-old boy. My son has ADHD and is home trying to get disability, so they let me take the baby every week and he usally stays about 3 days.

I am trying everything that I didn't do with my kids. I want him to learn and bring it home. I do not think the boy's parents parent very good (I don't want to get into that can of worms). So maybe I over analyze everything because I am so afraid of him also having ADHD.

He gets excited and grabs and scratches people's faces **hard**. He also grunts all the time, enough to make his face red and then he laughs like it's a joke.

He does not say any words yet, is this his way of talking? Should I be worried?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting! You may get some better answers if you can pick one of the issues to focus on -- the face scratching? his noises? (12 months is very young to expect actual words, I do know.)

Comment: Have you tried gently grabbing his hands, saying "No that hurts mommy" (or whoever is holding him) and tucking his hands at his sides? If you keep this up consistently he will likely stop. Hes probably enjoying the adults reaction to his flailing.

Comment: Actually I am his nana and yes I am trying everything that I didn't do with my kids. My son is ADHD and still is and I do not think they parent very good ( I don't want to get into that can of worms). So maybe I over analyze everything cause I am so afraid of him also having ADHD.My son is home trying to get disabilty so they let me take the baby every week and he usally stays about 3 days.So that saying "what happens at grandmas stays at grandmas" does not apply here, I want him to learn and bring it home.

Answer (score 2):

My daughter is 1.6 years old now. From my experience I can say, you need not to worry.

> he laughs like its a joke

Kids world is entirely different and we can't go and see whats happening in their world. Their, language, activities everything will be different. When he scratches others face people will make some sounds know, that make him happy. Just cut his nails properly. One year old baby scratches will not be painful if nails would have been cut properly.

Answer (score 0):

Children communicate very abstractly. Sometimes, they try to tell anyone who might listen to pay attention to their needs and they do it the way that is easier to them. Sometimes, the scratches and the pulling hairs gets them the wrong result and that confuses them more. Teaching a child not to hurt is very difficult, because hurting is not the effect they expect from their communicating their cause therefore that can be a lenghty and tricky guess.